# Max pixel issue downloading a Sentinel image for my ROI

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to download a Sentinel image for my ROI but, it pops up an error I am not able to solve. Additionally, my ROI is also very small.

> Error: Export too large: specified 8030040147504 pixels (max:
> 10000000000). Specify higher maxPixels value if you intend to export a
> large area. (Error code: 3)

```
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterBounds (roi)
                  .filterDate('2019-05-01', '2019-07-31')
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)}) 
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
                  dataset.mosaic().reduceRegion(roi)
                  print (dataset, 'image collection sentinel')
                 
var visualization = {
  // min: 0.0,
  // max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B8','B4', 'B3'],
};
Map.addLayer(dataset,visualization, 'sentinel dataset');
var image = dataset .mean().clip(roi);
Map.addLayer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');
// // Export the image, specifying the CRS, transform, and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image.clip (roi),
  description: 'imageToDriveExample_transform',
  scale: 10,
  folder: 'Cloud_storage',
  maxPixels:1e10,
});
```

Comment: We'll need the definition of `roi` to be able to diagnose this. If it's a polygon you drew in the Code Editor, click on the blue button to the right of the "Imports" line at the top of the editor to obtain a text version.

Comment: hey, Kevin, I did not draw the polygon for my ROI. However, I chose a shape file to access the image of the area.

Comment: Perhaps you could try displaying the `roi` on the map? For example, maybe it has become an inside-out polygon somehow.

Comment: I was able to export the image from the code, I added the region: ROI in export syntax. However, the image is showing no data for the bands.